# Pairwise calculation in r

Tags: r

I have been thinking about a problem I have but I don't know how to express the problem to even search for it. I'd be very thankful if you could explain it to me.

So, I have a data set with the following format:

```
10 6 4 4
10 6 4 4
7 6 4 4
```

I want to conduct a pairwise calculation for which I need to sum each element to the other one by one. That is 1 with 2, 1 with 3, 1 with 4, 2 with 3, 2 with 4 and 3 with 4.

I thought to do a nested a loop in R which I read about it and I started like this:

```
for (i in 1:r-1) { ## r the number of columns
for (j in (i+1):r) {
....
}
```

I am stuck at this stage, I don't know how to express in codes what I need to do. I am sorry for posting a not progressed code, some advice would be very good that how I should go about it.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `combn` to create the "pairs":

```
(pairs <- combn(4,2))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    1    1    2    2    3
[2,]    2    3    4    3    4    4
```

Then `apply` across the rows of your data by summing these subsets by applying across the columns of the pairs:

```
dat <- matrix(c(10,10,7,6,6,6,4,4,4,4,4,4),ncol=4)
t(apply(dat, 1, function(x) apply(combn(4,2),2,function(y) sum(x[y]))))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]   16   14   14   10   10    8
[2,]   16   14   14   10   10    8
[3,]   13   11   11   10   10    8
```

Comment: The questioner will probably want to use `ncol(dat)` rather than `4` to pass to `combn`.

Answer (score 0):

You could slightly modify your loop:

```
d <- read.table(text='
10 6 4 4
10 6 4 4
7 6 4 4')

nc <- ncol(d)
r <- NULL
for (i in 1:nc) {
  for (j in 1:nc) {
    if (i < j) {                      # crucial condition
      r <- cbind(r, d[, i] + d[, j])  # calculate new column and bind to calculated ones
    } 
  }
}

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]   16   14   14   10   10    8
[2,]   16   14   14   10   10    8
[3,]   13   11   11   10   10    8
```

Answer (score 0):

Another application of `combn` but perhaps easier to understand:

```
apply(combn(ncol(dat),2), 2, function(x) rowSums(dat[,x]))
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
## [1,]   16   14   14   10   10    8
## [2,]   16   14   14   10   10    8
## [3,]   13   11   11   10   10    8
```

Here, the matrix `dat` is indexed by each column of the result of `combn` giving a matrix of two columns (the two columns to be summed).  `rowSums` then does the arithmetic.

Because I really like package *functional*, here is a slight variation on the above:

```
apply(combn(ncol(dat),2), 2, Compose(Curry(`[`, dat, i=seq(nrow(dat))), rowSums))
```

It should be noted that a `combn` approach is more flexible than using nested `for` loops for this sort of computation.  In particular, it is easily adapted to any number of columns to sum:

```
f <- function(dat, num=2) 
{
  apply(combn(ncol(dat),num), 2, function(x) rowSums(dat[,x,drop=FALSE])) 
}
```

This will give all combinations of `num` columns, and sum them:

```
f(dat, 1)
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
## [1,]   10    6    4    4
## [2,]   10    6    4    4
## [3,]    7    6    4    4
f(dat, 2)
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
## [1,]   16   14   14   10   10    8
## [2,]   16   14   14   10   10    8
## [3,]   13   11   11   10   10    8
f(dat, 3)
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
## [1,]   20   20   18   14
## [2,]   20   20   18   14
## [3,]   17   17   15   14
f(dat, 4)
##      [,1]
## [1,]   24
## [2,]   24
## [3,]   21
```